# Google looker studio scheduled email delivery not working for distribution lists

Tags: analytics, reporting, looker-studio, looker, distribution-list

I am trying to trigger scheduled email through Google Looker Studio. It is working for individual emails, however not working for the distribution emails. No one in the distribution list is receiving the emails when triggered to distribution emails.

Expecting help from anyone so that the trigger enables sending emails to the ones in distribution list